# terms_set: failed to find minimum_should_match field

Tags: elasticsearch

**I'm totally confuse when trying to use "terms_set" query.**

First, [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html), it's say that `minimum_should_match_field` is an optional field. But im getting this `failed to create query: No minimum should match has been specified` error if I don't include it in the request. Like below:

```
POST bw-ecom-1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "category": { 
        "terms": [
            "Men's wear", "Women's wear", "Unisex"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when I include the `minimum_should_match_field`. I got another error `failed to find minimum_should_match field`. I've tried to pass several value too. For instances `required_matches`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

**This is a document of my index:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "white t-shirt for men",
    "short_description": "",
    "category": [
        "Men's wear",
        "Women's wear",
        "Unisex"
    ],
    "min_price": 10000,
    "max_price": 15000,
    "discount": "0.05",
    "currency": "VND",
    "created": "2022-03-13",
    "modifided": "1678700615438",
    "indexed_at": "2022-03-13",
    "variants": [
        {
            "color": ["red"],
            "size": ["XL", "L"],
            "form": "short sleeve",
            "price": 12000,
            "variant_id": "v-001",
            "label": "red short sleeve men t-shirt"
        }
    ],
    "inventory": [
        {
            "variant_id": "v-001",
            "storage_qty": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason you use the [terms_set](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) query, but `required_matches` **should be in the document**.

For example:

```
PUT /job-candidates/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "name": "Jane Smith",
  "programming_languages": [ "c++", "java" ],
  "required_matches": 2
}

PUT /job-candidates/_doc/2?refresh
{
  "name": "Jason Response",
  "programming_languages": [ "java", "php" ],
  "required_matches": 2
}

GET /job-candidates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "programming_languages": {
        "terms": [ "c++", "java", "php" ],
        "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
GET /job-candidates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "programming_languages": {
        "terms": [ "c++", "java", "php" ],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": "Math.min(params.num_terms, doc['required_matches'].value)"
        },
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yes, `minimum_should_match_field` and `minimum_should_match_script` are optional. But you need to use at least one of them :)

Comment: I tried `minimum_should_match_script` and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I forgot to mention why I want to use `terms_set`. It's because I want to search for documents that contain all terms. In that case, you should do this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "category": {
        "terms": ["Men's wear", "Women's wear", "Unisex"],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": "params.num_terms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```